# Getting values from the spinner inside the list

Tags: android, list

I've create the android application program using list adapter that extends the list activity....Inside the list i am having the spinner.. how can i get the value from the spinner inside the list..tell some idea.Thanks in Advance..

Comment: paste your code here for list adapter and how you are constructing your views.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=h9pkB6PE

Comment: u got any idea about my project

Comment: You already accepted another answer, why should I be spending time with your project anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ::

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        String str = mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        // getting item id by this
            myId = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you only have one spinner in the list. In that case you can get the view by id of that spinner and fetch the value. If there are more than one then you need to add different tags to them while adding them to the list (in ListAdpater) and get these views from tag and get the value.