# How to use the spinner inside the list that extends listactivity

Tags: android, listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting values from the spinner inside the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346001/getting-values-from-the-spinner-inside-the-list)

I've create the android application.. I have the list inside that,  spinner is display based on the arraylist.. But the spinner is empty. how can i get the value of the spinner.If possible means tell some idea. Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Show us the code you use to create/fill that spinner

Answer (score 0):

Did you call this?

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where adapter is an `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: i call this adapter.but it wont work inside the list adapter

Answer (score 0):

Uthra you need to replace this code

```
final Spinner spinnertwo= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptertwo = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,mspinner);
         spinnertwo.setAdapter(adaptertwo);
```

with this

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can create an array list like this inside strings.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="planet_prompt">Choose a planet</string>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
        <item>Jupiter</item>
        <item>Saturn</item>
        <item>Uranus</item>
        <item>Neptune</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

As @svidnas mentioned, use the link for [more info](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html)

Comment: Just a question: you tell OP to replace some part of his code... but where did he post that code?!? I'm confused...

Comment: Marco it is a duplicate question, she posted the same question yesterday on which I was helping until she accepted an answer, there she pasted this code. I have flagged it duplicate already.